# Leksah, jump to definition within current package and to names defined in packages installed in Sandbox

Tags: haskell, leksah

I'm using Leksah 0.15.0.1 built with ghc 7.10.1.

Here is the problem :

If I ctrl+click on a function name which is from a system wide installed library then Leksah goes to the definition, just fine!

**However**, this (go to definition) does not work for

1) functions defined within the currently edited package

2) functions defined in packages that are located in a sandbox.

For example in the picture below, I can jump to the definition of `SDL.QuitEvent` but not to the definition of `AppInput`.

Which is strange because `AppInput` is defined in the same file that I am editing and `SDL.QuitEvent` is defined in a system wide installed cabal package.

Any idea how to fix this? What might be going wrong ?'

[image]

[image]